# Qt + Android: Location of java files common to different projects

Tags: android, qt

In Qt for Android you have java files included in your project. The location is configured with the variable ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR in the project file.

That location also contains other files specific to the project (resources etc).

But if these java files are common to different projects you should have separate copies, one on each project inside the respecitive ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR

My question is if anyone knows a way to specify a directory of java files independent of the location of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still fairly new to developing Android apps in Qt but recently I started the journey and ran into the exact same problem your having; I wrote some common C++ / Java code that I wanted to share between a few different apps. The C++ code was easy (shared library) however as you say what about the Java code, I don't want to have copies of the same Java code in each project directory.

It took a bit but I figured out a way to do it that is pretty easy to do.

When compiling a Qt Android project after the C++ code is compiled/linked an ANT script is run which compiles the Java code (hence why you just need to stick Java source files and not compiled JAR files in the src folder).

The ANT script, which is part of the Android SDK, by default looks in the src folder and compiles any Java files found there. So all you really need to make sure is that before the ANT script is run all the Java files you want to use as part of your App are located in that folder.

The ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR variable tells qMake where to find the files it needs to copy to the android-build folder (including any project specific Java code) but what we want is a custom target which is run some time before the ANT script is executed to manually copy our common Java files to the src folder so they can compiled into the App too.

To do this in my *.pro file I added the following:

```
# This line makes sure my custom manifest file and project specific java code is copied to the android-build folder
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android

# This is a custom variable which holds the path to my common Java code
# I use the $$system_path() qMake function to make sure that my directory separators are correct for the platform as you need to use the correct separator in the Make file (i.e. \ for Windows and / for Linux)
commonAndroidFilesPath = $$system_path( $$PWD/../CommonLib/android-sources/src )

# This is a custom variable which holds the path to the src folder in the output directory. That is where they need to go for the ANT script to compile them.
androidBuildOutputDir = $$system_path( $$OUT_PWD/../android-build/src )

# Here is the magic, this is the actual copy command I want to run.
# Make has a platform agnostic copy command macro you can use which substitutes the correct copy command for the platform you are on: $(COPY_DIR)
copyCommonJavaFiles.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $${commonAndroidFilesPath} $${androidBuildOutputDir}

# I tack it on to the first target which exists by default just because I know this will happen before the ANT script gets run.
first.depends = $(first) copyCommonJavaFiles
export(first.depends)
export(copyCommonJavaFiles.commands)
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copyCommonJavaFiles
```

When you run qMake the Make file that gets generated will have the following:

```
first: $(first) copyCommonJavaFiles

copyCommonJavaFiles:
    $(COPY_DIR) C:\Users\bvanderlaan\Documents\GitHub\MyProject\MyProjectApp\..\CommonLib\android-sources\src C:\Users\bvanderlaan\Documents\GitHub\build-MyProject-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\MyProjectApp\..\android-build\src
```

So now when I build my common C++ gets linked in as a shared library and my common Java code gets copied to the src directory before the ANT script compiles all the Java code and gets copied into my app with any project specific Java code I might have. This eliminates any need to keep copies of the Java files in multiple locations in my source tree or need for external build scripts/tools to setup my working space before I compile.

I hope this anwsers your question and works for you.

*Until next time think imaginatively and design creatively*

Comment: Thank you for your extensive reply. I have learned some new things about qmake by the way :-)

Perhaps the only issue still is that if you had some error on your java code the QtCreator editor point to the source in the copy folder rather than the original so you may be doing some editing that might be destroyed later.